# Read template from Azure user-defined outputter

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake

I am pretty new to Azure Data Lake. I would like to create user-defined outputter that uses a file template to generate the output file. The question is what is the best way to store and retrive the template file in the outputter? The simplest and easiest way is to embed the template file into the U-SQL assembly and read it from assembly resources. But this is not flexible solution - if it is required to change template it will be required to re-deploy the outputter dll. The correct way seems to be to store the template in Azure Data Lake Storage, but I am not sure how to read the template from the outputter's C# code.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible to reference external files inside user defined outputter. You are basically processing row by row and outputting to streams.

User defined outputter is having programming model and I dont see it supporting accessing something outside the assembly. [User Defined Outputter Programming Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-u-sql-programmability-guide#use-user-defined-outputters)

What I would suggest is: have boolean flags defined for different output formats you want to support and then handle the rows accordingly. This way, you can have single outputter to support multiple output formats.

Already built-in outputter [Outputters.Text()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/operators/outputters/outputters-text) supports multiple formats by changing delimiter. You can also think of something similar.

```
OUTPUT @sampleData TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/Text.txt" USING Outputters.Text();
OUTPUT @sampleData TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/Text_outputHeader.txt" USING Outputters.Text(outputHeader: true);
OUTPUT @sampleData TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/Text_charFormat.txt" USING Outputters.Text(charFormat: "string");
OUTPUT @sampleData TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/Text_delimiter.txt" USING Outputters.Text(delimiter: '|');
OUTPUT @sampleData TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/Text_dateTimeFormat.txt" USING Outputters.Text(dateTimeFormat: "D");
OUTPUT @sampleData TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/Text_encoding.txt" USING Outputters.Text(encoding: Encoding.UTF32);
OUTPUT @sampleData TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/Text_escapeCharacter.txt" USING Outputters.Text(escapeCharacter: ':');
OUTPUT @sampleData TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/Text_nullEscape.txt" USING Outputters.Text(nullEscape: "null");
OUTPUT @sampleData TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/Text_quoting.txt" USING Outputters.Text(quoting: false);
OUTPUT @sampleData TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/Text_rowDelimiter.txt" USING Outputters.Text(rowDelimiter: "\u0003");
OUTPUT @sampleData TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/Text_charFormat_nullEscape_escapeCharacter.txt" USING Outputters.Text(charFormat: "string", nullEscape:"NULL", escapeCharacter:'#');
OUTPUT @sampleData TO "/Output/ReferenceGuide/BuiltIn/UDOs/Text_charFormat_encoding.txt" USING Outputters.Text(charFormat: "string", encoding:Encoding.Unicode);
```

As you are processing row by row, ideally you dont need template file. You can handle the logic in the assembly. but, if you need template file, you can keep the file in the resource file and deploy the same with the assembly. You can also define configuration file and deploy with the assembly, based on the need.